# Second order ODE $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let consider ordinary differential equation of the form

$$t^2y''+3ty'+y=0$$

This is equivalent to

$$y''+\frac{3}{t}y'+\frac{1}{t^2}y = 0$$
which looks better. But how does one find the solutions here? I guessed one of them is $y(t)=\frac{1}{t}$, but guessing shouldn't be the method here. I feel as though I needed a smart substitution. Any hints?

Comment: Since $y_1(t) = \frac{1}{t}$ is a solution, you can write $y_2(t) = k(t) \frac{1}{t}$, and solve for $k(t)$, making $y_2$ a solution too. But I suppose that you don't want this. I'll see if I think of something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
t^2y'' + 3ty' + y = 0
$$
first thing to notice is that a trival (yet insightful(I believe) separation of terms)
$$
t^2y'' + 2ty' + ty' + y = \dfrac{d}{dt}t^2y' + \dfrac{d}{dt}ty =0
$$

$$
\dfrac{d}{dt} \left(t^2y' + ty\right) = 0
$$
or 
$$
t^2y'+ty = C_1
$$
this is a first order ode which you can solve readily.

Comment: That is indeed insightful +1.

Comment: Very nice!  Very well done indeed! +1!